# Adding Static JSON directly on Factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

my project depends on a bulk of static JSON. for the high performance of my Application. i just trying to avoid storing these static JSON in separate json file instead of that, i directly hard coded into Angualr js Factory.is there any issue by doing like this.

```
'use strict';

myApp.factory('appUtilityData', function() {
   return {
      navlistData:[
          {
              "listId": "1",
              "listName": "Home",
              "listValue": "home",
              "listHref": "/home",
              "listIcon": "images/icons/icon1.png"
          },
          {
              "listId": "2",
              "listName": "Pick Movie",
              "listValue": "movieList",
              "listHref" : "/movieList",
              "listIcon": "images/icons/icon2.png"
          },
      ]
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues. But, I would prefer you use [angular constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant). Here is an example:

```
app.constant("myConfig", {
        "url": "http://testappser",
        "port": "80"
    })
```

Comment: thanks for your Reply... i really trying to avoid the separate JSON  file is because of my Application Performance.what will happen if i store a bulk of static JSON (minimum10 kb)  in  app.constant?? is any delay in initial loading of my app.

Comment: Basically it depends on how / when you need access to those static data! If you need it immediately after you app load you its better to download in one go.. if you need it later and on some user interactions you can bring it later through Ajax to static JSON files..

Comment: my last doubt. there is a definite delay between loading static JSON through app.constant and  Ajax to static JSON files.. right??  ajax will have high access time??

Comment: when you use app.constant, there is no Ajax.. its loaded when your angular app is downloaded and starts running. Where as Ajax will be a new request to get the static JSON file from server.. but the high access time depends on your data size..

Comment: yeah that i know.. my doubt is to  get the static JSON file from the Local.